# No installed app with label 'emp' Django and what i dont understand is that i did put the app in the installed apps

Tags: python, django, makemigrations

No installed app with label 'emp' Django
and what i dont understand is that i did put the app in the installed apps [this is the insstalled apps part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCztX.png)

Comment: make sure you are in the correct virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Accroding to the rules of Django , after creating any app then you have to assign it into the INSTALLED_APPS section which is exixts under urls.py file . From your given image, I can see that, you created two app and that are 'emp' and 'EmployeeApp' but you don't assign those into  INSTALLED_APPS section . That's why the error is occurred.
To fix this issue , just assign the app name into the INSTALLED_APPS section .

Example :

```
INSTALLED_APPS=[
.
.
.
'rest_framework',
'emp',
'EmployeeApp',
]
```

Comment: You can assign apps with `module...<AppConfigClass>` too. The entries `md5diablo` made are true too.